# How to join two different tables in one query?

Tags: php, sql

I have two tables:

`grades` (id, subject_code, subject_description,midterm, final, final_remarks)

`scholars` (id, Id Number, Lastname, Firstname, Middlename, School, Year, Semester, Course, Action)

How can I join them?

I want to get the subject_code, subject_description, midterm, final, and final_remarks from grades, and fullname from scholars?

Comment: What is the common column between the tables?

Comment: without any reference key you can't join this two table.

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) There is a [Manual for learning MYSQL Syntax you know](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html)

Comment: Have you done any attempts? if yes please post your code.

Comment: You have to add the grade `id` field to scholar table and use `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: There are many tutorials on SQL, they should all explain how to do a simple join like this. Have you done any studying of SQL first?

Answer (score 0):

Need a column into scholars table grades_id field which grades table's id.

```
SELECT DISTINCT gr.subject_code, gr.subject_description, gr.midterm, gr.final, gr.final_remarks, sl.fullname
FROM grades gr
LEFT JOIN scholars sl ON (gr.ID = sl.grades_id)
WHERE 1=1
```

Comment: I think 1=1 is not secure.

Comment: Its just starting condition, it is not important condition. If you want to remove , it will not effect.

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution of your problem -

```
SELECT grades.subject_code , grades.subject_description , grades.final , grades.final_remarks , scholars.fullname 
from grades 
join scholars ON grades.lastname = scholars.lastname ;
```

Comment: the common was lastname

Comment: ohk not a big issue , do this answer helped you ??

Comment: You're missing a table name after `join`.

Comment: @iAmLan The question doesn't show a `lastname` column in `grades`, how can that be the common field?

Comment: even i am thinking of that how lastname can be common , here common means column name must be same @iAmLan

Comment: @Barmar - im sorry i forgot to type it

Comment: @iAmLan It doesn't make sense to use lastname as the foreign key. What if you have two students with the same last name?